# replace a object when i add new object in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

my onplaceSelected like this:

```
onPlaceSelected = {
        place => {
            sendToState(updaterecentActivity({
                    customerInfo: {
                        shipAddress: [...(recentActivity?.customerInfo?.shipAddress ?? [{
                            name: ''
                        }]), {
                            name: place?.formatted_address
                        }],
                    },
                });
            }
        }
```

when i added a new object it replace a old object lastly added object in ReactGoogleAutocomplete,I don't know where is my mistake.

I have also tried,

```
shipAddress: [
...recentActivity?.customerInfo?.shipAddress ??
[{name: ''}].concat({name: place?.formatted_address}),
],
```

Comment: why use this ```  [{name: '' }]) ```  ???

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.